# How to get values of selected dropdown box display in url

Tags: php

I'm setting up an eCommerce website and I need to select product quantity user enters in drop down. I have tried this but it gives me last quantity not the selected. I'm still in the process of creating the **addtocart.php** file but before that I need to pass the values so that I can use them in a later stage.

I have implemented the following code

```html
  <div class="product-cartq">
    <div class="product-quantity pull-left">
     <span>Quantity:</span>
     <select name="quantity_option">
          <?php for($qty = 1; $qty < 11; $qty++){
          echo '<option value="'.$qty.'">'.$qty.'</option>';
          }?>
     </select>
   </div>
     <div class="btn_addtocart">
      <form method="GET" action="cart.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_option" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="add to cart"/>
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I can't proceed as I'm unable to get the value. Any suggestions or improvements on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
<form method="GET" action="cart.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="product-cartq">
    <div class="product-quantity pull-left">
     <span>Quantity:</span>
     <select name="quantity_option">
          <?php for($qty = 1; $qty < 11; $qty++){
          echo '<option value="'.$qty.'">'.$qty.'</option>';
          }?>
     </select>
   </div>
     <div class="btn_addtocart">

      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id; ?>">
      <input type="hidden" name="quantity_option" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="add to cart"/>

   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes this seems to work, I had to remove `<input type="hidden" name="quantity_option" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>">` as it was repeating the quantity again. Anyway, thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The select control is outside form tag.